# DPS airport to Nusa Lembongan in late afternoon?

Tags: ferries, bali

We’re considering staying on Nusa Lembongan while in Bali, but unsure if it will be possible to do so the first night. We'll arrive at DPS airport around 14:30. Let’s give a healthy margin of error and say we’ll be out of the airport by 16:00. Is it realistic to try to reach Nusa Lembongan the same day, or is that cutting it pretty close? The last fast ferry from Sanur a cursory search turned up leaves at 17:15; which seems doable. But if there are any delays, are there any later options? Is it generally a good idea?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Ferries avoid travel at night, and sunset in Bali is shortly after 6 PM all year around, so you will be hard pressed to find later services than 17:15.  If you miss the last ferries, your only option would likely be to charter a water taxi, but this won't come cheap and it's quite dangerous to boot (small boats with dubious safety standards, hard to see hazards at night, hard to get help at night etc).

In your shoes, I would pick one of these options:

1. If you're not too picky about where you stay, **don't book anything and take your chances**.  If you can catch the last ferries from Sanur, great, pick a place on Lembongan on or right before arrival.  If you miss the ferry, *tidak apa-apa*, overnight in Sanur and keep going the next morning.
2. If you want to play it safe, **book cheap accomodations in/near Sanur and head over on the first boat in the morning**.  Less time on Lembongan, but you can prebook your accommodations on both sides and have zero stress on arrival.

Comment: If it was just me, I might go *tidak apa-apa*, but since we'll have kids with us, we'll probably go with option 2 instead. Thanks for the input!

Comment: @deceze I'd do the same.  Enjoy your trip!

Comment: Update: we would have totally missed that ferry, as our plane was an hour late. 